# Determining the value of a landing page missing Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Using Google Analytics, if someone lands on my site onto a page without Google Analytics, and then clicks a link to a page with Google Analytics, can I see that?

I have an e-commerce site where most of the pages are using Google Analytics. However, my blog is not. The blog is hosted in a subdirectory of the same domain (e.g. `www.mysite.com/blog`).

I want to know the value of my blog, specifically whether any traffic into my main site is coming from my blog (for example a click-through from `mysite.com/blog/any-article-no-analytics` to `mysite.com/some-page-with-analytics`).

The reason is that I'm deploying a new site, but want to preserve all high-value pages, some of which may be blog articles.

Answer (score 1):

> Using Google Analytics, if someone lands on my site onto a page
>   without Google Analytics, and then clicks a link to a page with Google
>   Analytics, can I see that?

Yes you should be able to pull out this information. In Google Analytics go to `Behaviour` >> `Site content` then `Landing pages`. You can drill down on the landing page(s) and click the `Entrance path` tab, this will show you were the traffic came from (internal/external).